# Adjust frame of UITableView Background View?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am setting a label inside of an empty table view's background view, which is placing the label in the middle of the tableview.

I'd like to move that label up a bit, so it's near the top of the table view, however the code below isn't working:

```
UILabel *messageLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.bounds.size.width, 20)];

messageLbl.text = @"NO REGISTRATIONS FOUND";
messageLbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Sansation-Bold" size:20.0f];
messageLbl.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
messageLbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[messageLbl sizeToFit];

//set back to label view
self.tableView.backgroundView = messageLbl;
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
self.tableView.backgroundView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.bounds.size.width, 100);
```

Comment: If you add the messageLbl to tableHeaderView instead of table backgroundView, it comes as a header of the TableView. It comes on top, just below the NavigationBar.

Comment: I'd like to move that label up a bit, so it's near the top of the table view. It's confusing line. You just want that label near to the top and it's not a bit.:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another easy solution is to add your `messageLbl` to `tableHeaderView`:

```
UILabel *messageLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.bounds.size.width, 50)];

messageLbl.text = @"\n\n NO REGISTRATIONS FOUND";
messageLbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Sansation-Bold" size:20.0f];
messageLbl.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
messageLbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
messageLbl.numberOfLines = 0;

[messageLbl sizeToFit];

//set back to label view
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = messageLbl;
```

[image]

Comment: @AdamG Happy coding :-)

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution is just by adding `\n` at the end the of text and set no of lines to `0`. Try this

```
messageLbl.numberOfLines = 0;
messageLbl.text = @"NO REGISTRATIONS FOUND\n\n\n\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you were hiding the Y axis behind Navigation bar
try it by setting some Y axis height & Don't forget to add SubView

```
UILabel *messageLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, self.tableView.bounds.size.width, 20)];
messageLbl.text = @"NO REGISTRATIONS FOUND";
messageLbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Sansation-Bold" size:20.0f];
messageLbl.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
messageLbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[messageLbl sizeToFit];

//set back to label view
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
[self.view addSubview: messageLbl];
```